# Touchscreen not working after installation

Tags: dell, 16.04, tablet, touchscreen

The touchscreen of a Dell Venue 11 Pro workes well in a live system of Ubuntu 16.04. After installation the touch support is completely gone. What can I do to restore it? I have already had a look at the modules and found out that several hid-modules including hid_multitouch are loaded in both variants. The kernel version seem to be the same, too.